# Calling npm install from grunt

Tags: build, gruntjs, npm

I started using grunt for my project and I like it so far. I installed some tasks via npm and everything works fine. I would like to have one basic task in my gruntfile that does a grunt install before starting the other tasks, so that every npm dependency is definitely loaded. I need this because if I extend my gruntfile with new tasks, i don't want to run npm install on my jenkins machine by hand and I would like to do this without an extra script running before grunt. Is there a way to achieve this or is this totally crazy?

Is there a problem with loading npm tasks inside grunt after running my first task? Is this even possible? How do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this is totally crazy.

To run `grunt`, it's required that `node_modules/grunt` exists. To get this to work, you'll need to either `npm install` or `npm install grunt` - if you know you're going to need more modules, just go with the first option.

I don't know how Jenkins work, but it probably allows you to run some dependency installation before running your tests (aka `npm install`).

If you don't want to run installation steps everytime, you can push `node_modules` to your repository. Will reduce network latency, at least.

Comment: Ok. I didn't want to install grunt via grunt :-) I just wanted to install the npmTasks via grunt, but I think i simply run a npm install before grunt. :-)

Comment: The global installation of `grunt-cli` is who makes `grunt` command available. `grunt` __package__ is required by `grunt` __command__ / `grunt-cli` package.